# Forgot to advance the film for four frames

Tags: film

I forgot to advance the film for four frames is there any chance that my film won't be blank? Btw I'm using Lomography Konstruktor F camera.

Answer (score 4):

If you exposed the same frame 4x, and your exposures were even close to proper, then there’s a near zero probability that your frame is blank. In fact, it should have elements from all 4 scenes stacked. You’ve essentially created a quadruple exposure.

Comment: Note that @hueco mentions *frame*, not *film* like in your question ("any chance that my **film** won't be blank?"). The rest of the roll will be fine (if you exposed the other frames correctly). It's just that frame that will be overexposed

Comment: @TimStack that’s a great point!